# Convert List of Array into single Array

Tags: java, arrays, list

How to convert List of arrays into a single array in Java. Is there any predefined function to use?

Below is the list of arrays, I want to iterate and keep all values in a single array.

```
List<Integer[]> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

Integer[] resultArray = {};
```

Is there efficient way to implement?

Answer (score 7):

Java 8's stream make this pretty easy:

```
Integer[] resultArray = 
    integerArrayList.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 4):

With `Stream`s:

```
Integer[] resultArray = integerArrayList.stream () // create a Stream<Integer[]>
                                        .flatMap (Stream::of) // flatten to a Stream<Integer>
                                        .toArray (Integer[]::new); // generate Integer[]
```

Similarly, you can produce an `int[]`:

```
int[] resultArray2 = integerArrayList.stream () // create a Stream<Integer[]>
                                     .flatMap (Stream::of) // flatten to a Stream<Integer>
                                     .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // convert to IntStream
                                     .toArray (); // generate int[]
```